# cstring << no operator found which takes a right-handed operand of type 'std::string'

Tags: c-strings

I have an assignment in which we are supposed to use cstrings instead of strings.  The problem lies in the << operands in three out of the five cout statements.  Can anybody help me figure out how to get the operand errors to go away?  The code is posted below.  The error locations are listed in bold!  Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int strLength, wPointer;
string custNumber, year, workOrderNumber;

string workOrder = "91800w940770";

strLength = workOrder.length();
wPointer = workOrder.find('w', 0);
custNumber.assign(workOrder, 0, wPointer);
year.assign(workOrder, wPointer + 1, 2);
workOrderNumber.assign(workOrder, wPointer + 3, strLength);

cout << "The length is " << strLength << endl;
cout << "The location of the w is " << wPointer << endl;
std::cout << "The customer number is " **<<** custNumber << std::endl;
cout << "The year of the order is " **<<** year << endl;
cout << "The order number is " **<<** workOrderNumber << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

custNumber, year and workOrderNumber are strings.

Include `<string>` to use them with **<<** operator.

Answer (score 0):

The  library "<<" function won't work on std::strings. You could create your own function that would output the characters of the string one char at a time